# Where can I find the photos autosynced by Google?

Tags: sync, photos

My Android phone autosyncs all the photos I took to my Google account. Where could I find it? I'm using Google cloud services to sync photos.

I tried looking at my Google Drive, but it says that I don't have any back-up files. I also checked in Google+, but there are no photos.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find them [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/instantupload). If they are not there then your phone is probably not actually uploading them.

If it's not uploading photos check that in Settings > Accounts > Google > "your account" > Google Photos is checked. Also check in Google+ > Settings > Auto-backup that it is configured to upload, there are also some settings to control when (on wifi/charging etc).

Comment: Oh, my phone doesnt uploading the photos. How could I sync it to my google account ?